# Redirect install(Downloader) wizard but already installed

Tags: redirect, install, downloader

My magento site was running good but suddenly i got the problem in project.My site redirect only install wizard page and i am unable to open admin front page.So Please help me out.

Comment: To be clear, are you redirected to the installation wizard or the downloader?  If installation, you don't have an `app/etc/local.xml` file.  If the downloader, you don't have an `app/Mage.php` file.

Answer (score 4):

**Solution of Redirect install(Downloader) wizard but already installed**

> Open this file : app/Mage.php
>
> Find this below code :

```
$localConfig = simplexml_load_file($localConfigFile);
```

> Change it to the below code :

```
libxml_disable_entity_loader(false);
e$localConfig = simplexml_load_file($localConfigFile);
```

> Note : Clear cache or check to private window

Comment: Please do not edit a core file.

Answer (score 3):

Magento redirects to the install wizard if there is no `app/etc/local.xml` file. In this file, all the configuration stuff is stored. So if that is not present, Magento assumes that you did not install it yet. Most probably you have to restore that file.

Answer (score 0):

The common reasons for Magento 1 redirects you to install wizard are:

- app/etc/local.xml is not present
- app/etc/local.xml contains invalid data
- - check xml syntax and missing parameters
- - some of the placeholders present (i.e.: `{{date}}`)
- - Date is not in the correct format. Type `date` on your terminal and paste the result in the `<date>` node.